# React Typescript prop error in ListItem (Material UI component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui, react-props

I'm having an issue with the ContainerComponent and ContainerProps, i think the problem is that "li" is of type string, and i need to explicity define it as type of
React.ElementType<React.HTMLAttributes>, but i don't know how.

```
<ListItem
  ContainerComponent="li"
  ContainerProps={{ ref: provided.innerRef }}
  {...provided.draggableProps}
  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
  style={getItemStyle(
      snapshot.isDragging,    
      provided.draggableProps.style
  )}
>
```

The Error I'm getting:

No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Type '"li"' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<HTMLAttributes> | undefined'.
Type '{ ref: (element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ref' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes'.ts(2769)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the component, but if it wants ElemenType, try giving it type - `ContainerComponent={(<li/>).type}`

Comment: "I think the problem is that "li" is of type string" It's not that.  It's getting inferred as a string literal which is fine.  The type `React.ElementType<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>` resolves to a union of about 70 string literal element names.  I guess `"li"` isn't one of them?  I can't see the whole list.

Comment: `Type '"li"' is not assignable to type '"object" | "abbr" | "address" | "article" | "aside" | "b" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "caption" | "cite" | "code" | "col" | "colgroup" | "dd" | "del" | "details" | "dfn" | ... 61 more ... | undefined'`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Not sure what is happening, but `'li'` is the default value of `ContainerComponent` if [not provided](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9782be8402751a2b82f3e658bd4cd81158cf0807/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L174)

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova thanks this worked!

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes you are right, so the easiest solution would be just to remove the prop

Comment: Perfect, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by writing:

```
<ListItem
ContainerComponent={(<li />).type}
ref={provided.innerRef}                                             
{...provided.draggableProps}                                                 
{...provided.dragHandleProps}
style={getItemStyle                                                      
snapshot.isDragging,                                                      
provided.draggableProps.style)}
```